# Which FunctionalInterface should I use?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

I was learning to write some lambda representation as [FunctionalInterface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html).
So, to add two integers I used:

```
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> biFunction = (a, b) -> a + b;
System.out.println(biFunction.apply(10, 60));
```

Gives me the output **70**. But if I write it as this

```
BinaryOperator<Integer, Integer, Integer> binaryOperator = (a, b) -> a + b;
```

I get an error saying

> Wrong number of type arguments: 3; required: 1

Isn't `BinaryOperator` a child of `BinaryFunction`? How do I improve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### [`BinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html)

Since `BinaryOperator` works on a *single type of operands and result*. i.e. `BinaryOperator<T>`.

> Isn't BinaryOperator a child of BinaryFunction?

Yes. `BinaryOperator` does `extends BiFunction`.
But do note the documentation states(formatting mine):

> This is a specialization of `BiFunction` for the case where the
>   *operands and the result are all of the **same type***.

The complete representation is as:

```
BinaryOperator<T> extends BiFunction<T,T,T>
```

hence your code shall work with

```
BinaryOperator<Integer> binaryOperator = (a, b) -> a + b;
System.out.println(binaryOperator.apply(10, 60));
```

---

#### [IntBinaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/IntBinaryOperator.html)

If you're supposed to be dealing with two primitive integers as currently in your example (*add two integers I used*), you can make use of the `IntBinaryOperator` FunctionalInterface as

```
IntBinaryOperator intBinaryOperator = (a, b) -> a + b;
System.out.println(intBinaryOperator.applyAsInt(10, 60));
```

> Represents an operation upon two `int`-valued operands and producing
>   an int-valued result. This is the *primitive type specialization* of
>   `BinaryOperator` for `int`.

---

> I am using Integer, can I still use IntBinaryOperator

Yes, you can still use it ***but*** notice the representation of the `IntBinaryOperator`

```
Integer first = 10;
Integer second = 60;
IntBinaryOperator intBinaryOperator = new IntBinaryOperator() {
    @Override
    public int applyAsInt(int a, int b) {
        return Integer.sum(a, b);
    }
};
Integer result = intBinaryOperator.applyAsInt(first, second);
```

would incur you an overhead of *unboxing* `first` and `second` to primitives and then *autoboxing* the sum as an output to `result` of type `Integer`.

***Note***: Be careful of using *null-safe values* for the `Integer` though or else you would probably end up with a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using `Integer`, can I still use `IntBinaryOperator`?

Comment: @Mani In that case, preferably use `BinaryOperator`, since `IntBinaryOperator` would add an overhead of autoboxing and unboxing. See the edit in the answer.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the answer and explanation again.

Answer (score 6):

```
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> biFunction = (a, b) -> a + b;
```

can be represented by

```
BinaryOperator<Integer> binaryOperator = (a, b) -> a + b;
```

But generally you want to perform arithmetical computations on `int` and not `Integer` in order to avoid unboxing to compute (Integer to int) and boxing again to return the result (int to Integer) :

```
IntBinaryOperator intBinaryOperator = (a, b) -> a + b;
```

As a side note, you could also use a method reference instead of a lambda to compute a sum between two `int`s.
[`Integer.sum(int a, int b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#sum(int,int)) is what you are looking for :

```
IntBinaryOperator biFunction = Integer::sum;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using `Integer`, can I still use `IntBinaryOperator`? The other answer and document reads primitive type operation for it.

Answer (score 4):

> Isn't BinaryOperator a child of BinaryFunction?

Yes, it is. If you look at source code of `BinaryOperator`, you see:

```
public interface BinaryOperator<T> extends BiFunction<T,T,T> {
    // ...
}
```

So you just have to fix your syntax:

```
BinaryOperator<Integer> binaryOperator = (a, b) -> a + b;
System.out.println(binaryOperator.apply(10, 60));
```

> How do I improve it?

You can use `IntBinaryOperator`. It simplifies sytax even more:

```
IntBinaryOperator binaryOperator = (a, b) -> a + b;
System.out.println(binaryOperator.applyAsInt(10, 60));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using `Integer`, can I still use `IntBinaryOperator`? The other answer and document reads primitive type operation for it.

Comment: @Mani yes, it will be automatically unboxed from `Integer` to `int`

Comment: I got it. Thank you for the answer again.