# BinaryOpertor for List<Integer> to add the lists

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, functional-interface

In previous question I asked previously [Which FunctionalInterface should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53893602/which-functionalinterface-should-i-use)

Now I was trying to add to `List<Integer>` and not just two **Integers `a` and `b`**, such that each index adds to the same index of another list.

I had previously

```
 BinaryOperator<Integer> binaryOperator = Integer::sum;
```

for adding two integers using `binaryOperator.apply(int a,int b)`. Is there a similar way like

```
BinaryOperator<List<Integer>> binaryOperator = List<Integer>::sum;
```

and then get the result in `List<Integer> cList`?

Comment: This is in general called *zipping*, and is discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17640754/3788176).

Comment: Thank you. Good to know more. @Andy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to perform some computation on the elements at corresponding indices (in this specific case the summation) there's no need to use a `BinaryOperator`, instead use `IntStream.range` to generate the indices:

```
// generates numbers from 0 until list.size exclusive 
IntStream.range(0, list.size())....

// generates numbers from 0 until the minimum of the two lists exclusive if needed
IntStream.range(0, Math.min(list.size(), list2.size()))....
```

The common name for this type of logic is "zip"; i.e. when given two input sequences it produces an output sequence in which every two elements from the input sequences at the same position are combined using some function.

There's no built-in method in the standard library for this, but you can find some generic implementations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip).

for example, using the `zip` method in the accepted answer of the linked post, you could simply do:

```
List<Integer> result = zip(f.stream(), s.stream(), (l, r) -> l + r).collect(toList());
```

or using method reference:

```
List<Integer> result = zip(f.stream(), s.stream(), Math::addExact).collect(toList());
```

where `f` and `s` are your list of integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IntStream.range()` to iterate over elements, then `mapToObj()` to map them to their sum and the `collect()` them in the third list.

Given that your lists are of ***same size***

```
List<Integer> first = List.of(); // initialised
List<Integer> second = List.of(); // initialised
```

you can get the third list as :

```
List<Integer> third = IntStream.range(0, first.size())
                               .mapToObj(i -> first.get(i) + second.get(i))
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In terms of BinaryOperator, you can represent it as :

```
BinaryOperator<List<Integer>> listBinaryOperator = (a, b) -> IntStream.range(0, first.size())
            .mapToObj(i -> first.get(i) + second.get(i))
//          OR from your existing code
//          .mapToObj(i -> binaryOperator.apply(first.get(i), second.get(i)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Or you can make it more readable by abstracting out the logic into a method and using it as :

```
BinaryOperator<List<Integer>> listBinaryOperator = YourClass::sumOfList;
```

where `sumOfList` is defined as :

```
private List<Integer> sumOfList(List<Integer> first, List<Integer> second) {
    return IntStream.range(0, first.size())
            .mapToObj(i -> first.get(i) + second.get(i))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is define your own utility method whose single task is *zipping* the two input lists :

```
<T> List<T> zip(final List<? extends T> first, final List<? extends T> second, final BinaryOperator<T> operation)
{
    return IntStream.range(0, Math.min(first.size(), second.size()))
        .mapToObj(index -> operation.apply(first.get(index), second.get(index)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This way, you can sum your two input lists as :

```
zip(first, second, Integer::sum)
```